Binding TonConnect to the service, not the device
Terms:

We have Telegram WebApp application in which we want to make wallet binding by user via TonConnect.
When binding a wallet, we save the address of this wallet on the server in connection with the user's Telegram account.
We save the address to see on the server that this particular Telegram user bought NFT from our collection.

Problem:
If a user binds a wallet on device 1 and then opens our Telegram WebApp on device 2, we can show him the wallet address (because it is saved on the server), but it is not clear whether it is possible to restore the full functionality of the wallet binding on device 2.
Example:
Open TonKeeper to create an NFT purchase transaction exactly from the linked wallet on device 2, as can be done on device 1 where the user linked the wallet. I have a feeling that on device 2 TonKeeper will open independently and the user can pay from another (unbound) wallet and then we won't be able to realize that NFT bought our Telegram user.
How do we bind the user's wallet to our service and not to the user's device?

Terms: Please read [ask] and [tour]/

@0stone0 What the problem?
